# ERROR in app: Exception on /predict [POST]

Tags: python, post, flask, server-error

i encountered the following error msg on the browser upon running my apps on gcloud :

**Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.**

On reviewing the log files, it shows :

**ERROR in app: Exception on /predict [POST]**

And my codes are below :

```
@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict(): 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        BizUnit = request.form.get('BizUnit')
        Region = request.form.get('Region')
        Category = request.form.get('Category')
        sel = (BizUnit, Region, Category)
        dict = {'COO': 0, 'Finance': 1, 'HR': 2, 'AMER': 0, 'APAC': 1,
                'EMEA': 2, 'Resources': 0, 'Facility': 1, 'Services': 2}
        sel_num = ([dict[sel[0]], dict[sel[1]], dict[sel[2]]])
    final_features = [np.array(sel_num)]
    prediction = model.predict(final_features)

    output = round(prediction[0], 2)

    return render_template('index.html', prediction_text=
                           'Spends should be $ {}'.format(output))
```

Would greatly appreciate if anyone can advise some pointers to solve this.  Thanks

Comment: @app.route('/predict', methods=['GET','POST']). Add get method as well.

Comment: unfortunately, the same error appears when I added your suggestions.